# Web Browser Performance

Tags: web

I'm setting up an Rpi to use mainly for web browsing. I noticed that it was far too slow to try to use ice weasel or chromium, but midori's speed is approaching being almost usable. I am hoping to use a rich text editor in the browser and have edits appear in real time.

I already got a bit of an extra speed boost by enabling turbo mode in the overclock settings.

Would booting from a USB disk resolve my issue? Are there any other tips?

Comment: I would not expect too much a jump in performance while booting from USB and not SD.

Answer (score 2):

You should try out the Foundation's enhanced Epiphany browser.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/web-browser-released/

It claims

> Epiphany brings a host of neat features to Raspberry Pi, including:
>
> ```
> Much-improved HTML5 support
> A JavaScript JIT
> Hardware-accelerated video decoding
> ARMv6-optimized blitting functions
> Better interactivity during page loading
> Faster scrolling
> ```

Comment: That actually made a huge improvement in text editor speed, and has given added confirmation to my theory that the wireless adapter is also very slow.